# Change zedgraph selected curve color

Tags: c#, colors, zedgraph

On a ZedGraph pane, it is possible to set a `CurveItem` as "selected".

```
zedGraphControl.GraphPane.CurveList[0].IsSelected = true;
zedGraphControl.Refresh();
```

This will change its color to `Color.Gray` as far as I can see.

Is it possible to change this selected-state color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of such a property but you can accomplish this by manually overriding the MouseClick event of the ZedGraphControl and set the color of the "selected" CurveItem, something like:

```
private void zedGraphControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var curve in zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList)
        {
            curve.Color = Color.Black;
        }

        CurveItem nearestItem;
        int nearestPoint;
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.FindNearestPoint(e.Location, out nearestItem, out nearestPoint);
        if (nearestItem != null)
        {
            nearestItem.Color = Color.Red;
        }
        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

**UPDATE**: Looking at the source code of http://www.opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/zedgraph/Line.cs.html and http://www.opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/zedgraph/Selection.cs.html it seems that Line.DrawCurve is using static property Selection.Line. Without modifying source it would be hard to change this behaviour.

Part of Line.cs:

```
public void DrawCurve( Graphics g, GraphPane pane, CurveItem curve, float scaleFactor )
{
    Line source = this;
    if ( curve.IsSelected )
        source = Selection.Line;
```

Selection.cs:

```
/// The <see cref="Line" /> type to be used for drawing "selected"
/// <see cref="LineItem" /> and <see cref="StickItem" /> types
 /// </summary>
public static Line Line = new Line( Color.Gray );
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I already did. I discovered later the `IsSelected` property, so I wondered if I would be able to use it.

Comment: So that's not changeable without modifying the source code. I can accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

The selected line is a static property, but NOT read-only. One can change the format by resetting the Selection.Line property:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ZedGraph.Selection.Line.Width = 3;
   ZedGraph.Selection.Line.Color = Color.Red;
   ...
}
```

After resetting the selection line, all selected lines will draw as specified.